How to restart Control Center?
Through the desktop widget for Screen Time on my M3 Max MacBook Pro with macOS 15.1.1, I noticed how usage for today was around 35 hours (!), 12.5 of which were occupied by the com.apple.controlcenter process.
Browsing Activity Monitor didn't return any relevant result for that specific process, even though looking directly for "Control Center" returned the expected result.
Here is a screenshot of System Settings > Screen Time > App & Website Activity, filtered down for only my Mac in devices.

As you can see, it shows Control Centre as being an in-use app for close to 14h, something that I have honestly never seen before. Safari is running, but I have certainly not kept it in focus for 12h! YouTube was running on the iPad as a background music for my workday for 6h (checking the iPad page of Screen Time), but it was never once opened on Mac.
The Tips app was running, but in focus for perhaps 10 minutes while I was writing a blog post? Then what is 5h of Dailymotion? I have no app that is called like that, no process running that answers to it, nor any Safari tab that has it.
Any idea what may be going on and what I could do to solve it? Just a bug in Screen Time, perhaps?

You may need to fill in some blanks. What makes you think that Control Center is "stuck?" Something like control center is always going to be on, mostly as a background process, until you bring it to the front.How do you get CPU usage info out of Screen Time? Control Center is readily visible in my Activity Monitor. So make sure you understand how the Process Name col. is sorted.

@SteveChambers: thank you. I have updated the question with a lot of details. I hope this helps.

So your tilte question is easy to answer: restart the whole Computer. Then there are questions in your post, which can be googled, like what is Dailymotion: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dailymotion. You'll have to search for Control Center in your local language in Activity Monitor.

I've seen that already quitting Safari improves things. The culprit appears to be a course on design I am following (Bring Your Own Laptop) which seems to hosts their videos on Vimeo and Dailymotion. Problem is: if the tab stays open in Safari even without it being active, it counts against screen time, possibly also consuming resources.
